# Align elements in form of a table horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am making an App in which I have a slide in/out menu. When this menu is displayed I want it to show the images in two rows. Since there are many images, I want to have a horizontal scroll to navigate through them as well as arrows.

My problem is that I am not able arrange these images in two rows in a horizontal way. They keep appearing in a vertical way.

Currently, the arrow on the right goes away when I add more images, and when I scroll to the end it shows again. I do not know why I cannot manage to have a determined scroll area without moving the other elements.

```js
var step = {};
var stepsOpen = false;

function onHandleClick() {
    if (stepsOpen) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("StepMenu")[0].setAttribute("style", "top: -77px;");
        document.getElementsByClassName("Handle")[0].setAttribute("style", "top: 102px;");
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("StepMenu")[0].setAttribute("style", "top: 102px;");
        document.getElementsByClassName("Handle")[0].setAttribute("style", "top: 281px;");
    }
    stepsOpen = !stepsOpen;
}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    background: #000000;
}
html {
  font-family: 'SST Japanese Pro';
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.Title{
  background: linear-gradient(#000000, #2a2a2a);
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  position:fixed;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 102px;
  line-height: 102px;
  z-index:2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.StepMenu{
  background: #2a2a2a;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  height: 179px;
  width:100%;
  top:-77px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.stepContainer{
    float:left;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items:baseline;
}

.Stitle {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    width: 200px;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    padding-left:20px;
}

    .Steps {
        width:90%;
        height: 179px;   
        overflow: auto;
    }

        .lines {
            height: 89.5px;
            width: 100%;
            display: table;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

img {
    width: 97px;
    height:55px;
    background-image: url('../res/image/tuna.jpg');
    margin-left: 12.5px;
    margin-right: 12.5px;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    display: table-cell;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}

.arrow {
    border: solid white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}

.right {
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #959595;
    border-right: 0px;
}

.left {
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid #959595;
    border-left: 0px;
}

.Handle {
    width: 87px;
    top: 102px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 4px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display:flex;
}

.Htext {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #959595;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }

.Harrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-right:10px;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #959595;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Step</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="Title">Recipe Title</div>
      <div class="StepMenu">
          <div>
            <div class="Stitle">Part1</div>
            <div class="Stitle">Part2</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="stepContainer">
            <div class="arrow left"></div>
                <div class="Steps">
                <div class="lines">
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                </div>
                <div class="lines">
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>
                    <img></img>

                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="arrow right"></div>  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Handle" onclick="onHandleClick()">
          <div class="Htext">STEPS</div>
          <div class="Harrow"></div>
      </div>

      <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added the float:left for the image in CSS. This may helpful fo you. 
Here is my fiddle link..

https://jsfiddle.net/b6jpkdhk/

```
img {
    width: 97px;
    height:55px;
    background-image: url('../res/image/tuna.jpg');
    margin-left: 12.5px;
    margin-right: 12.5px;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    display: table-cell;
    float:left;
}
```